# Android: how to reduce trigger duration of onSingleTapConfirmed?

Tags: java, android, gesturedetector

I have got a view where I use :

```
 class GestureTap extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
      
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
}
}
```

I think that onSingleTapConfirmed is launched after a too long duration.

Is it possible to reduce this duration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration is a final value, you can not change it.
so,you may adjust your code strategy,like this：

```
int MOVE_RANGE= 100;
int TIME_LONG_PRESS = 1000;
Runnable r = Runnable();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (Math.abs(mLastMotionX - x) > TOUCH_MAX|| Math.abs(mLastMotionY - y) > TOUCH_MAX) {
                //Beyond the long press range
                handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            mLastMotionX = x;
            mLastMotionY = y;
            // Start counting
            handler.postDelayed(r, TIME_LONG_PRESS );
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it is what I did! Regards.